# Sql to show what column name from where clause

Tags: sql

I have a relatively simple piece of SQL code as show here:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 
FROM table 
WHERE column_1 IS NULL OR column_2 IS NULL OR column_3 IS NULL
```

Obviously nothing too groundbreaking there, but I've been asked to find out if there is a way to add a fourth column that will output the name of the column(s) that trigger the where clause, preferably one that can be incorporated into the above SQL statement, if possible.

Comment: What if 2 or 3 of them are null?

Comment: I need to see the name of each column that produces a null, if possible.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You could use string operations and ifs to reach your goal. You have not specified the database type you will run this query against, so the following example is tested for MySQL 8:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, TRIM(CONCAT(IF(column_1 IS NULL, ' column_1', ''), IF(column_2 IS NULL, ' column_2', ''), IF(column_3 IS NULL, ' column_3', '')))
FROM Test
WHERE column_1 IS NULL OR column_2 IS NULL OR column_3 IS NULL
```

Perhaps there is an easier way of doing this, but this seems to do the job. It is of course impractical for large queries and needs us to reconstruct the logic of the where clause. So, it does not seem advisable or only for automatically generated queries.

An easier method might be to query all where conditions separately instead. Then you know which of the alternative methods was used.